# Preventing role reading others posts

Tags: custom-post-types, users, permissions, user-roles

I've got a custom post type that I want to allow a specific user role to add posts to, however they must not be able to read posts from others.

Here's my custom post type code:

```
register_post_type('product', array(
    'labels'                => create_post_type_labels('Product'),
    'public'                => TRUE,
    'query_var'             => TRUE,
    'rewrite'               => array('slug' => 'products', 'with_front' => FALSE),
    'capability_type'       => 'directory',
    'capabilities'          => array(
        'edit_post'         => "edit_directory",
        'read_post'         => "read_directory",
        'delete_post'       => "delete_directory",
        'edit_posts'        => "edit_directorys",
        'edit_others_posts'     => "edit_others_directorys",
        'publish_posts'       => "publish_directorys",
        'read_private_posts'    => "read_private_directorys",
        'delete_posts'        => "delete_directorys",
        'delete_private_posts'    => "delete_private_directorys",
        'delete_published_posts'  => "delete_published_directorys",
        'delete_others_posts'   => "delete_others_directorys",
        'edit_private_posts'    => "edit_private_directorys",
        'edit_published_posts'    => "edit_published_directorys"
    ),
    'supports'              => array('title', 'author'),
    'has_archive'           => TRUE
));
```

And here's a screenshot of the role permissions:

[image]

The problem I'm having is my `directory contributor` user can still see the posts from the other users.

Can anyone spot an error in the way I am doing things here?

Comment: First you're not "doing things here", but clicking together stuff with a plugin - this is _not_ the default admin interface. Second, you're missing the mapping of meta caps IIRC.

Comment: Semantics aside, I had used code to replicate the capabilities set in this plugin. However I didn't realise I needed to make the meta capabilities unless I wanted to do something against the default. After the mapping code from here (http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types) it now works as desired. Thanks Kaiser, want to add that as an answer?

Comment: Ben, I added you a more in depth explanation that works without some bogus filter callback - no idea how he got on that one. But for the future: Please make your questions more detailed, stuff all the needed info inside (plugin, anyone?) and show your efforts _in code_.

Comment: Any progress? ..

Comment: @kaiser Damn... completely forgot to update you, on it now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

The problem is, that you have a custom `capability_type`. This means, that this post type will be handled *differently* from default post types, that have a capability type of `post`: Users need to be granted access to this capabilities. Important thing here: This is a good decision.

### Foundation

What you're missing is mapping the capabilities to their corresponding meta capabilities. A short explanation straight from Codex:

> `edit_post`, `read_post`, and `delete_post` - These three are meta capabilities, which are then generally mapped **to corresponding primitive capabilities** depending on the context, for example the post being edited/read/deleted and the user or role being checked. Thus these capabilities would **generally not be granted directly to users or roles**.

Then there're the other *4 primitive capbilities*: `edit_posts`, `edit_others_posts`, `publish_posts` and `read_private_posts`. All those (7 in total) caps are assigned in the capabilities array and checked on various locations in core.

But then there're **another 7 capabilities** that are *not checked against*, but *only mapped* inside `map_meta_cap()`. When you look at the [source of `map_meta_cap()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.7.1/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L1002-1275), then you'll see 17 cases for the `switch` in total. Don't be confused by that, as not everything is related to posts, but to plugins activation, users and other stuff.

Now the core function `map_meta_caps()` checks which type of cap is checked, then starts filling an array of capabilities. Then at the end the following is returned:

```
return apply_filters( 'map_meta_cap', $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args );
```

Now let's take a look at the [core registration process](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.7.1/wp-includes/post.php#1249-1251) of post types: `map_meta_cap` is `NULL` per default and **if not explicitly set**, it's `FALSE`.

And when we look at a user capability check with [the `has_cap()` function](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/1c8b834b0c5b9b147e259174fe601fb357163a6a/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L956), we can see that `map_meta_cap()` will be called to retrieve all needed capabilities and then [it will be looped through and checked against](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/1c8b834b0c5b9b147e259174fe601fb357163a6a/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L977-982) the resulting capabilities from the mapped caps.

### The rule

> If you assign a `capability_type`, you better set `map_meta_cap` to `TRUE`.

Comment: Thank you @kaiser, I didn't realise I had to map the custom capabilities, after I had done this the user permissions behaved themselves.